# Need to Manage/Integrate two Jars run by 32 bit and 64 bit JVMs separately

Tags: java, jvm, swt

I have to move some data from tool-1 to tool-2. I am using java for reading data from Tool-1 and writing into Tool-2.

Tool-1 was built in 32 bit windows architecture, so it gives a .dll file which can be supported only by 32 bit jvm. Okay I used 32 bit jvm to run jar1 which reads data from Tool-1.

Tool-2 has no such limitations, so writing data into Tool-2 can be done using jar2 which will be running using 64 bit jvm.

Now to manage this process[read-write], I thought of creating a SWT app which runs in 64bit jvm.

Running 'SWTApp' using 32 bit jvm - fails SWTApp
Running 'SWTAPP' using 64 bit jvm - fails data reading part from Tool-1.

Now, I can try a web UI and treat two different jars as two different microservices will do the job.

But is there some thing which I can try to run my 'SWTApp'.

Comment: You say that running your app "fails" - what do you mean by that? What errors are you seeing? Any stack traces that you can provide?

Comment: You can use any number of messaging solutions to allow these two processes to communicate.